# The set of algebraic numbers is countable

Tags: field-theory

> The set of algebraic numbers is countable

The last $2$ lines (bijection) in the proof below doesn't seem convincing enough to me, can somebody explain it in more detail. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: It is clearer to prove as a separate lemma the result that a countable union of finite sets is countable. In effect, this proof seems to implicitly contain a proof of this lemma, and thus obscures the essential simplicity of the fact that there are only countably many algebraic numbers.

Comment: I think it might be helpful if you tell us where you get stuck in the proof.

Comment: I think it's easier to see it by noting there are a countable number of polynomials each with a finite number of roots.  The polynomials of degree  $n$ are in bijection with $\Bbb Q^{n+1}$ so there's a countable number for each degree and a countable union of countalbe sets is countable, so ...

Comment: It only weakly hints at the desired bijection $ℕ → A$, where $A$ denotes the set of all algebraic integers. That seems to be the main issue. What is your concrete problem? Can you imagine the bijective map that’s being hinted at? Can you see that it is truly bijective?

Comment: @GregoryGrant this answers the question, thanks